# How to return a set of objects with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I did [a lesson](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) about `Spring Boot` and it works perfectly. But what if I want to return a set of objects ? I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266289/how-to-get-list-of-objects-via-requestbody-in-spring-boot-api) but it doesn't work. How can I do it correctly ?

***With one object (it works):***

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(template, name));
}
```

***With many objects (it doesn't work):***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Greeting> greeting() {
    Greeting greeting1 = new Greeting(1, "One");
    Greeting greeting2 = new Greeting(2, "Two");
    List<Greeting> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(greeting1);
    list.add(greeting2);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you compare your original method to your newly made one (with a `List`), you'll notice a few differences.

First of all, within the `@RequestMapping` annotation you're now using the properties `consumes` and `produces`. `produces` is not a problem here, because you are producing a response that should be JSON. **However** you're not consuming anything, so you should leave away the `consumes`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Greeting> greeting() {
    Greeting greeting1 = new Greeting(1, "One");
    Greeting greeting2 = new Greeting(2, "Two");
    List<Greeting> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(greeting1);
    list.add(greeting2);
    return list;
}
```

*As a sidenote, you might also notice that you used the `@ResponseBody` annotation. Putting it here won't cause any errors, but it is not necessary, because if you followed the Spring tutorial correctly, you should have annotated your controller with `@RestController` and by doing that, you already tell Spring that it will use a response body.*

Comment: Just to note: Jackson also has an XML serialization addition. As soon as you put that on the classpath it isn't so certain anymore what Spring produces by default, I've seen endpoints switch from JSON to XML serialization because of it. It is best to be specific with the produces property.

Comment: I'm using a Set<Greeting> as a return value - while other attributes of the object are returned as JSON, the `set<>` is not included in the response. I am using Spring Boot 3. Do you have any hints on that?

Comment: Nevermind. **Remember to create getter's and setters** as they are necessary for Spring's(Jackson) serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Let Say we have list of CarDetails Pojo and we want to return them back

```
@RestController
public class CarDetailController {
  @GetMapping("/viewAllCarDetailList")
    public List<CarDetail> retrieveAllCarDetails() {
        List<CarDetail> contacts = new ArrayList<CarDetail>();

        CarDetail objt = new CarDetail();
        objt.setCarModel("hyundai");
        objt.setSubModel("I10");
        CarDetail objt2 = new CarDetail();
        objt2.setCarModel("hyundai");
        objt2.setSubModel("I20");        
        contacts.add(objt);
        contacts.add(objt2);
        return contacts;
    }
}
    public class CarDetails {

            private String carModel;
            private String subModel;
// Will haave Setter getter and hash code equls method
//and constructor
    }
```

This JSON will be output:-

```
[
    {
        "carModel": "hyundai",
        "subModel": "I10"
    },
    {
        "carModel": "hyundai",
        "subModel": "I20"
    }
]
```

[image: output in Postman]

Comment: What if we want to add a field value to the arryas? (something like this { "carModels" : [{objec1}, {object2}]}. Is there any way to do it without creating a seperate object?

Comment: Do you want the responce like:-  { "carModels" : [{I10}, {I20},{Inovoa}]}, Could you plesae confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet I did for this. Remove the "consume" from your @RequestMapping annotation because you are not using that in your method.

```
@RestController
public class GreetingsController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "greetings", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Greeting> greeting() {
        Greeting greeting1 = new Greeting(1, "One");
        Greeting greeting2 = new Greeting(2, "Two");
        List<Greeting> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(greeting1);
        list.add(greeting2);
        return list;
    }

    public class Greeting
    {
        private String message;
        private int count;

        public Greeting(int count, String message)
        {
            this.count = count;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage()
        {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct but when I was facing something a bit different I was getting  list of empty objects. The reason was that I did not implement `toString()` in my model class.