# Returning arraylist in Spring boot and google cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, gcloud

I am using spring boot and google app engine, in that an api which returns arrylist is not showing response in rest service
Here is the code,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "homescreen/market/news", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<RssFeedItems> marketNews(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
```

after Wrapping this list into a Pojo class as below, response is coming,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "homescreen/market/news", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RssFeedItemList marketNews(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
```

Please tell me how to return arraylist in springboot + gcloud

There are some link for spring boot but not for combination of spring boot and gcloud,
[Spring boot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719142/how-to-return-a-set-of-objects-with-spring-boot)

Comment: is your controller annotated with `@RestController` ?

Comment: Yes, it is having annotation

Comment: can you try with returning `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(List<RssFeedItems>) instead of just `List<RssFeedItems>` and change return type to `ResponseEntity`, and suitable HttpStatus.OK etc

Comment: Ok... Thank you I will try and let you know

Comment: :( , failed again. Response changes like this, {"rssFeedItems":[{"abc":"xys.... . Previously it was [{"abc":"xys....". I want to keep contract/wadl unchanged.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong, `List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("hello");
        l.add("world");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(l);` I am getting `["hello","world"]`

Comment: Also output with link in OP: `[{"anInt":1,"name":"One"},{"anInt":2,"name":"Two"}]`

Comment: Great, but is it on Google cloud ?

Comment: Can you help me understand how google cloud has anything to do with rest api with json response,

Comment: Yes, solution works fine only for spring boot it is not working along with Google app engine.

Comment: okay, what error you are getting?

Comment: No error at all, empty response with 200 status code.