# How to get mapping of array of subclasses in @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to implement endpoint for RestController in SpringBoot application. I expect that I will get POST request with body like that:

```
    {
      order: [
        {
         name: "Product1",
         type: "Fresh",
         expiryPeriod: "10"
        },
        {
         name: "Product2",
         type: "Frozen",
         manufacturingDate: "2017-03-08",
         storageTemp: "-40"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Accordingly I have abstract class Product and 2 sub-classes: FreshProduct and FrozenProduct.
The question is: how can I get `List<Product>` by @ResponseBody?

Comment: You have to return `Map<String,ArrayList<Map<String,String>>` from your rest controller endpoint rest Jackson will manage

Comment: This is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719142/how-to-return-a-set-of-objects-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Set type in yout abstract class like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FreshProduct.class, name = "fresh"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FrozenProduct.class, name = "frozen")}
)
@Data
static abstract class AbstractProduct {
    String name;
    String type;
}
```

And set type name in your sub-classes like this:

```
@JsonTypeName("fresh")
static class FreshProduct extends AbstractProduct {

}

@JsonTypeName("frozen")
static class FrozenProduct extends AbstractProduct {

}
```

More information about jackson-annotations : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: Please! Clarify what is the annotation @Data, from what package, and for what is it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have got correct result without @Data!

Comment: It'a a lombok annotation for getter/setter generation. More info: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment: I have got field "type" equals null in all objects. Do you know is it possible to keep original value in this field?

Comment: @MichaelZal Try to remove field "type" from AbstractProduct. Jackson include this field twice to json in my example.