# Send java UUID list with post request vie postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

Anybody Please help me in sending java UUID list via postman.
I tryed this way

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/alerts/sent/recipientstatistics")
    public List<SentAlertRecipientStatistics> getRecipientStatisticsForSentAlerts(@RequestBody List<StatisticsRequest> uuids) {}
```

and this way of sending via postman

```
    [{"notifHisUUID":"0000000a-0019-3000-806c-bea5b65658cf"}]
```

and getting error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.List.<init>()
```

My request class is

```
public class StatisticsRequest {

private List<UUID> notifHisUUID;

public List<UUID> getNotifHisUUID() {
    return notifHisUUID;
}

public void setNotifHisUUID(List<UUID> notifHisUUID) {
    this.notifHisUUID = notifHisUUID;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem lies in JSON that you are sending. You declare `"notifHisUUID"` like it was a string field, but it should be an array instead.

```
[
  {
    "notifHisUUID": [ "0000000a-0019-3000-806c-bea5b65658cf" ]
  }
]
```

Comment: And one question also, what if  my controller method is so

@PostMapping(path = "/alerts/sent/recipientstatistics")
    public List<SentAlertRecipientStatistics> getRecipientStatisticsForSentAlerts(@RequestBody List<UUID> uuids) {}

meaning that what if I want to get list of UUIDs, without a wrapper object, how will the postman json object be?

Comment: Then it would be `[ "0000000a-0019-3000-806c-bea5b65658cf" ]`. If this doesn't work, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35267809/6700091) answer (especially the part about jackson dependency)